# Self-Signed SSL Cert in Lighttpd Causing 404s

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, lighttpd, certificate

Hey guys, I wanted to try out SSL on my server so I decided to create some self-signed SSL certificates as outlined [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-lighttpd-create-self-signed-ssl-certificates.html). After going to the `document-root`, firefox did indeed allow me to accept the certificate and stuff. But when I actually tried to access files within the `test` directory, it kept throwing 404s. If I switched it to http instead of https, it worked.

I checked the access.log and it showed this:

```
my.ip server.ip - [05/Jan/2010:01:33:08 +0100] "GET /test/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 345 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6"
```

So it seems like even though I am requesting as https, it is requesting the file as http. My `document-root` in lighttpd.conf is `/var/www`, but for the ssl section I set it as `/var/www/test`, could there be a conflict right there? Should I make them separate directories?

I also tried doing a redirect so that supposedly, http requests to the test directory would be sent as https, but I don't think it's working, maybe I did it wrong.

Here is the relevant information from my lighttpd.conf file, I would appreciate any help you guys can give. Thanks.

```
$SERVER["socket"] == "some.ip:443" {
  server.document-root = "/var/www/test/"
  var.basedir = "/var/www/test/"
  ssl.engine = "enable"
  ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/some.ip/server.pem"
}

$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
  url.redirect = ("^/(test.*)" => "https://some.ip/$1")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the file `/var/www/test/test/index.html` exist?  If not, then accessing `/test/index.html` with a docroot of `/var/www/test` is going to rightly throw a 404.  Try keeping everything the same between the HTTP and HTTPS vhosts, and work from there.

Comment: Wow, you just helped me realize that being that the document-root is /var/www/test so I had to access it at some.ip/index.html. It worked, can't believe I spent hours trying to figure that out. Thanks.